# How do I get notified when a PFObject is saved to my Parse backend?

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I have followed the Quick Start Guide for parse:
https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_data/mobile/ios/native/existing

I'm using this code to save a PFObject:

```
PFObject *testObject = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"TestObject"];
testObject[@"Bookmarks"] = @"Restore Successful";
[testObject saveInBackground];
```

Below is what it looks like when my PFObject is saved to my Parse backend:
[image]

I would like to receive some sorta notification when this happens. Like an email, a text or a push notification. Anything that works.

Comment: you have the call back handlers that tell you when something is saved, is this not enough? or do you need something external to the app for some reason? in this call back block method you can then execute something that does what you want to do from above

Comment: Also, check out Cloud code - After Save

Comment: If you'd like me to show you what I mean, I have the full code implementation for you

Comment: @Larcerax If you could please, that would be awesome.

Comment: Yep, so, I'll warn you first, that this may be simpler than you thought, but you'll get the clue, its' all client side

Answer (score 0):

Parse's recommended way of doing it is using Cloud Code. Once, you [configure it](https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#cloud_code), in the `main.js` file add the following function:

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave("Posts", function(request) {

    // Gets called when a new object is added to the 'Posts' class.
    // From here you can proceed to send push notifications     

});
```

The `afterSave` method it's triggered after a new object is added to the specified class. If you want to manage, whether or not an object should be saved, look into `beforeSave`.

Comment: Do I have to look into beforeSave if I'm already saving the PFObject?

Comment: No, you should be fine using afterSave in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Quick example I just put together: example:

```
-(void)saveLesson {
    lesson = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"lessons"];
    PFObject *photo = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"photoslessons"];
    [photo setObject:[PFUser currentUser] forKey:@"userId"];
    [photo setObject:self.photoFile forKey:@"lessonimage"];
    [photo setObject:self.smallPhotoFile forKey:@"smalllessonimage"];
    [photo setObject:self.thumbnailFile forKey:@"thumblessonimage"];
    [photo setObject:self.originalFile forKey:@"originallessonimage"];
    PFACL *publicACL = [PFACL ACL];
    [publicACL setPublicWriteAccess:YES];
    [publicACL setPublicReadAccess:YES];
    photo.ACL = publicACL;
    self.photoPostBackgroundTaskId = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:self.photoPostBackgroundTaskId];
    }];
    [photo saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
        if (succeeded) {
            NSLog(@"Photo uploaded");
            NSNumber *userCount = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:0];
            lesson[@"textBody"] = [[[self contentView] descriptionText] text];
            lesson[@"title"] =  [[[self contentView] title] text];
            lesson[@"likes"] =  userCount;
            lesson[@"times_viewed"] =  userCount;
            lesson[@"featured"] =  @"false";
            lesson[@"userId"] = [PFObject objectWithoutDataWithClassName:@"_User" objectId:[PFUser currentUser].objectId];
            lesson[@"lessonimage"]= photo;
            [lesson saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
                if (succeeded) {
                    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"activesessions"];
                    [query whereKey:@"teacherid" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
                    [query getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {
                        if (object!=nil) {
                            [object setObject:lesson forKey:@"lessonid"];
                            [object saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
                                if (succeeded) {
                                    [(NSHLiveStudentProfileViewController*)self.navigationController.viewControllers[0] thisIsAHack];
                                    [[self navigationController] popToRootViewControllerAnimated:true];
                                }
                            }];
                        }}];
                } else if (error) {
                    NSString *  alertTitle = @"Error Saving Lesson";
                    UIAlertController * alert =  [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:alertTitle message:@"Please make sure to include both a title and description." preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
                    UIAlertAction* ok = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) { }];
                    [alert addAction:ok];
                    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:^{}];
                }
            }];
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Photo failed to save: %@", error);
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Couldn't post your photo" message:nil delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Dismiss", nil];
            [alert show];
        }
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:self.photoPostBackgroundTaskId];
    }];
}
```

So, that's a lot of code, but here's what we are going to do to help you out, lets add a method to send yourself an email:

First off, download load the pod mailgun:

then do this:

```
 Mailgun *mailgun = [Mailgun clientWithDomain:kMailGunAPIClientDomain apiKey:kMailGunAPIKey];
```

Also, sign up for a mail gun account, and send an email to yourself

Then in the code above, whenever and object is saved with "success" in the block like this:

first off, obviously change this:

```
 @"Peter Pan <peterpan.notarealemailaddress@gmail.com>"
```

to your mail address and then fill in the portions that require your API key and such that you get from MailGun, mailgun is cheap and this works for you immediately as soon as you set up the mail gun account (I dont work for mailgun, I'm jut a happy user)

```
[lesson saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
       if (succeeded) {

         [mailgun sendMessageTo:@"Peter Pan <peterpan.notarealemailaddress@gmail.com>"
                            from:@"Excited User <apeterpan.notarealemailaddress@gmail.com>>"
                         subject:@"Mailgun is awesome!"
                            body:@"and life is great!"];
```

boom!,

Here's the MailGun pod: https://github.com/rackerlabs/objc-mailgun

Sign up for a free account at: http://www.mailgun.com/

Test it out, the neat thing about this, is it's auto trigger and you can put whatever you want inside the email call that I've placed here, you also need to get AFNetworking:

get it here: https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking

This method doesn't require any sort of javascript cloudcoding and you can even substitute the body of your email for the informaiton you want to send to yourself. If you want to send yourself the USER ID of the person who just triggered your method, then there you have it, the email will be sent.

So you have this:

```
PFObject *testObject = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"TestObject"];
testObject[@"Bookmarks"] = @"Restore Successful";
[testObject saveInBackground];
```

Change it to this:

```
PFObject *testObject = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"TestObject"];
testObject[@"Bookmarks"] = @"Restore Successful";
[testObject saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
    if (succeeded) {
        NSLog(@"successfully SAVED!");
    }
}];
```

this is your custom save function:

```
-(void)customSaveFunction {
    PFObject *testObject = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"TestObject"];
    testObject[@"Bookmarks"] = @"Restore Successful";
    [testObject saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
        if (succeeded) {
             NSLog(@"successfully SAVED!");
             Mailgun *mailgun = [Mailgun clientWithDomain:kMailGunAPIClientDomain apiKey:kMailGunAPIKey];
            [mailgun sendMessageTo:@"Peter Pan <peterpan.notarealemailaddress@gmail.com>"
                                from:@"Excited User <apeterpan.notarealemailaddress@gmail.com>>"
                             subject:@"Mailgun is awesome!"
                                body:@"and life is great!"];
        }
    }];
 }
```

I showed the save lesson example as something where you can send multiple emails with multiple information in the email for differnet save triggers, but this code is useless to me now, this was used for major testing purposes only, so the custom save function that I posted above these few sentences is how you would do it yourself, or just put that same code in your viewcontroller or whereever you save your objects.

Comment: This seems awesome but how do I save what I need to be saved, instead of the photo example? All i need saved is PFObject *testObject = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"TestObject"];
testObject[@"Bookmarks"] = @"Restore Successful";
[testObject saveInBackground]; in Object IAP for Row Bookmarks string

Comment: Yeap, so Creagen, use the other method to save stuff in background, I'll show you

Comment: check the answer again, the way I'm showing you is the block method with a success handler so you'll know if/when it saved, in the portion that says, " if (succeeded) { .. } " this is where you plop your mail gun self email service

Comment: when you plop in the mailgun service using this method, if you want to send the oobject information to yourself, then just configure the email to send the strings to yourself, it's that easy.

Comment: But what about the -(void)saveLesson? What do i do with the code inside there? I'm assuming I don't just copy and paste it. :p

Comment: Oh yeah, this is my own code that I had to "depricate yesterday morning" so, this code is obsolete for your purposes, you dont have to do anything with this code, I'll recode something for you to use

Comment: @Creagen so yeah, just don't do anything with that code, but the code i posted for you under the "customSaveFunction" this is the code you want

Comment: Ok, I've added that code and I've installed mailgun but i still receive undeclared identifier mailgun

Comment: did yiou change the mailgun keys to your own keys? you need to set up mailgun at their web site, and there's some code you should comment out in mail gun as well, i'll post my files one sec

Comment: here's mailgun.m https://gist.github.com/anonymous/03f56643488808ad0cac    and here's mailgun.h, just copy and paste, I updated these myself so they work as of right now right now, the pod files won't do what you want them to do: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a48efc5053818717d374

Comment: but do keep the pod files, don't get rid of them, you just don't need most of the crap that's in there so i commented out and updated the stuff you want

Comment: @Creagen so what I mean, is this, change this "kMailGunAPIClientDomain" and this "kMailGunAPIKey" in your code with the stuff Mail gun gives you

Comment: @Creagen the first key is your SAND box key, you don't need to register a URL for testing, just register a sandbox and test it with your own email address

Comment: I think the email thing might be a little more than I bargained for. Unfortunately my entire app now has 20 warnings and 2 issues to do with parse, mailgun, and AFnetworking. I don't believe I understand the steps because whatever I did is not working well.

Comment: Well, if you copy the afnetorking and the mail gun Iike I show, then it works just fine, what are the errors, comment them

Comment: I'm pretty sure the errors you wil have are going to do with what libraries the mail gun files are asking for, and you need to use #import "AFNetworking.h" or this " #import <AFNetworking/AFNetworking.h>" only, that's it, no other afnetworking needs to be placed in the files

Comment: It says MGMessage.h file not found. That's coming from the Mailgun.h file you sent me.